# Will a static_assert in a POD ruin the POD?

Tags: c++, types, assert, static-assert

I was just wondering... Let's say I have a POD structure in C++. If I would put a `static_assert` in there, will it ruin the fact that it's a POD?

I know I can easily put it somewhere else, I'm just asking because I'm interested if I should or shouldn't do this...

In other words (more specific):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A 
{
    void* ptr;

    static_assert(sizeof(void*) == 8, "Pointer should have size 8; platform unsupported");
};

int main()
{
    // Is it guaranteed that this will evaluate to 'true'?
    std::cout << std::is_pod<A>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I believe not, `static_assert` kicks in on compile time, I don't think it's even incorporated on the resulting binary.. I don't have the standard beside me to get accurate answer

Comment: I guess `std::is_pod` can't really be wrong.

Comment: @DavidHaim Sure, that's the point of `static_assert`. Still afaik it is not defined how to implement it - so if it would generate a virtual member to do its work, it could theoretically ruin the `is_pod`. (Not that I would see why it would do that - but that's another story...) Right?

Comment: @atlaste A static assertion would be evaluated by the compiler when compiling and not by the compiled code's binary when run. So no code (virtual or otherwise) should be generated for `static_assert` ideally, otherwise it would be an inefficient implementation which just treats the `static_assert` as a runtime `assert`.

Comment: Note that nothing prevents you from bringing out the `static_assert` into the global namespace, if you want to take out any tiny possibility that it might not work as expected (there shouldn't truly be, as @legends2k also points out).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++11 a type is deemed [POD](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod) if it's

- [trivial](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial) (a scalar type, a trivially copyable class with a trivial default constructor, or array of such type/class)
- [standard layout](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout) (has no virtual functions, no virtual base classes, etc.)

Basically nothing that would hinder copying objects as if they're just constituted by raw bytes.

[`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert)s are there to validate something at compile-time and doesn't change the object layout or the triviality (or the lack thereof) in constructing, copying, etc. of an object. Hence adding any number of static asserts to a type (struct/class) shouldn't change the POD-ness of it.

You can check if the compiler is considering a type as POD using `std::is_pod<T>::value`. This wouldn't change before and after adding `static_assert`s to it.

This is all that the standard says regarding `static_assert`s. From **[dcl.dcl]**:

> In a *static_assert-declaration* the *constant-expression* shall be a constant expression that can be contextually converted to `bool`. If the value of the expression when so converted is true, the declaration has no effect. Otherwise, the program is ill-formed, and the resulting diagnostic message (1.4) shall include the text of the string-literal, except that characters not in the basic source character set (2.3) are not required to appear in the diagnostic message.

Comment: Sure, both are also evaluated compile-time, but afaik neither of them have an implementation constraint in the std that prohibits them from adding a virtual function, thereby violating the POD constraints, right?

Comment: The trivial part has the constraint that the class shouldn't have any virtual function. If it isn't trivial, it isn't a POD.

Comment: @atlaste : I don't recall an explicit ban (that would require checking the whole standard), but I believe that there is a wide consensus that compilers cannot add virtual functions just because they feel like it. The only ways to add a virtual function according to the standard is by declaring one or inheriting one. (IOW, the consensus is that this is an exhaustive list)

Comment: @MSalters OK, how about the more likely case that it will generate a helper variable to a non-POD structure. (f.ex. using template specialization you can create an 'asserting' structure based on the condition). I mean, it's a stupid implementation because you can use a typedef, but I guess it's allowed, right?

Comment: @atlaste: Now that's a fair point. You couldn't find that member via introspection (not a C++ feature), and you couldn't distinguish it from padding (as the compiler is free to add that for pretty much any reason). the compiler may pick a name which can't clash with your members (`__a` for instance).  Where the idea probably breaks down is that the generated helper variable doesn't have a _declaration_ in the source code. That's roughly the same logic as I brought up for virtual functions above. If a member must have a property that is introduced by its declaration, members cant be implicit.